# Can't subscribe to an event

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm just learning the ropes in mono and GTK# and I have encountered this problem.

I'm building a simple MVC the other way around -- from the top to the bottom (i.e. I'll build the interfaces/contracts later).

I've a Controller class:

```
public class ScanComparerController
{
    ScanComparerModel model;
    MainWindow view;

    public ScanComparerController ()
    {
        model = new ScanComparerModel ();
        view = new MainWindow ();

        view.Show ();

        view.Do += new MainWindow.DoHandler(PerformAction);
    }

    void PerformAction(MainWindow o, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}
```

I've a view class:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
    public event DoHandler Do;
    public delegate void DoHandler(MainWindow m, EventArgs e);

    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();

        btnGo.Clicked += buttonGo_clicked;
    }

    void buttonGo_clicked(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckConditions();

        if (Do != null) 
            Do (this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Now, for some reason, the view always believes that `Do == null`, while it shouldn't, because I add a listener to it right after the initialization. Still, my code looks exactly like the one [I refer to](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable).

I know it's probably something trivial I've missed, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT 1**

As suggested by undefined, I tried swapping the lines to:

```
view.Do += new MainWindow.DoHandler(PerformAction);
view.Show ();
```

Without success, however. Still, `Do == null` and `PerformAction` is never called.

**EDIT 2**

I tried eleting custom handler and switching to the generic EventHandler, as suggested by AdamBilinski. Still, without success.

**EDIT 3**

I double-checked and `Do` isn't referenced anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using your own event Handler? Why not just public event EventHandler Do;?

Comment: @AdamBilinski, none at all. Changed to EvenHandler, without success. It should be working, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try to swap the lines:

```
   view.Do += new MainWindow.DoHandler(PerformAction);

   view.Show ();
```

Subsribe first, then run the window cycle (`view.Show ()`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't change anything. I've updated my answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem. It was extremely trivial, sorry for bothering you.

The one class I haven't showed you was MainClass from Program.cs. It read:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init ();
        MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
        win.Show ();
        Application.Run ();
    }
}
```

Solved by changing to:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init ();
        var controller = new ScanComparerController ();
        Application.Run ();
    }
}
```

The moral from this story to be drawn is: **always check everything**.